# Show hide select box and select box option based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON array to hide the specific option and select box based on selection.Parent option and value is for selection and child option and value should be hide on that selection.It is not working as expected.Here what is currently happening when `40mm energisprosser`select from `Sprosser` it is hidding `Udluftningsventil`and `Udluftningsventil` select box and it also hide value from `Not` select box i.e `Ingen not` and `Not sider og top`.

Actually it should hide `Udluftningsventil`and `Udluftningsventil` select box only on that selection not .`Ingen not` and `Not sider og top`

When `55mm energisprosser` select it should hide `Ingen not` and `Not sider og top` only.

```js
var dependentspecArray = '{"width":{"50":{"parentoptions":["Bundtrin"],"childoptions":["Dørhåndtag"],"parentvalue":["Hårdttræ bundtrin"],"childvalue":["Håndtag for skydedør"]}},"height":{"50":{"parentoptions":["Sprosser","Sprosser","Sprosser"],"childoptions":["Udluftningsventil","Not","Not"],"parentvalue":["40mm energisprosser","55mm energisprosser","55mm energisprosser"],"childvalue":["all","Not sider og top","Ingen not"]}}}';

function selectSpec(ele) {

  var inputvalue = ele.value;
  var selectname = ele.name;
  var mainName = selectname.replace("specification_", "");
  param = "spectfication_" + mainName + "=" + inputvalue; //+"&color_type=1";
  var selectedvalue = jQuery.trim(jQuery('option:selected', ele).text());
  var selectedoption = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#' + selectname + '-accordion label').contents().get(0).nodeValue);
  restrictSpecification(selectedoption, selectedvalue);
}

function restrictSpecification(selectedoption, selectedvalue) {
  if (typeof dependentspecArray !== 'undefined') {
    var height = 50;
    jQuery.each(JSON.parse(dependentspecArray), function(firstkey, firstval) {
      if (firstkey == 'height') {
        jQuery.each(firstval, function(secondkey, secondval) {
          if (height <= secondkey) {
            var $i = 0;
            if (selectedoption == secondval.parentoptions[$i]) {
              jQuery('.a-layout').each(function() {
                //console.log(jQuery(this).parent('select').attr('id'));
                var selectIdInner = jQuery(this).parent('select').attr('id');

                var loopoption = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#' + selectIdInner + '-accordion label').contents().get(0).nodeValue);

                var loopoptionvalue = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text());
                if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery.trim(loopoption.replace(':', '')), secondval.childoptions) != -1 && jQuery.inArray(jQuery.trim(loopoptionvalue), secondval.childvalue) != -1 && jQuery.inArray(selectedvalue, secondval.parentvalue) != -1 && jQuery.inArray(selectedoption, secondval.parentoptions) != -1) {
                  jQuery(this).hide();
                } else {
                  jQuery(this).show();
                }
                if (loopoption == secondval.childoptions[$i] && selectedvalue == secondval.parentvalue[$i] && selectedoption == secondval.parentoptions[$i] && secondval.childvalue[$i] == 'all') {
                  jQuery('#' + selectIdInner + '-accordion-content').prev('h3').hide();
                  jQuery(this).parent('select').hide();
                } else {
                  jQuery('#' + selectIdInner + '-accordion-content').prev('h3').show();
                  jQuery(this).parent('select').show();
                }
              });
            }
          }
          $i++;
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="specification-head">
  <a id="specification_23-accordion" class="custom-accordion" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <label for="specification_23">
   Sprosser</label>
  </a>
</h3>
<div id="specification_23-accordion-content" class="two-fields accordian-specification">
  <div class="select-box">
    <select name="specification_23" id="specification_23" class="crossbaroption specification-option " onchange="selectSpec(this,'','','','');">
         <option class="a-layout" value="50">
            25mm energisprosser
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="51">
            40mm energisprosser
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="52">
            55mm energisprosser
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="53">
            85 mm gennemgående sprosser
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="54">
            18mm indvendige energisprosser
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="55">
            26mm indvendige energisprosser
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="56">
            45mm indvendige energisprosser
         </option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
<h3 class="specification-head" style="display: block;">
  <a id="specification_25-accordion" class="custom-accordion" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <label for="specification_25">
   Udluftningsventil</label>
  </a>
</h3>
<div id="specification_25-accordion-content" class="two-fields accordian-specification">
  <div class="select-box">
    <select name="specification_25" id="specification_25" class="specification-option " onchange="selectSpec(this,'','','','');">
         <option class="a-layout" selected="selected" value="75">
            Ingen udluftningsventil
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="198">
            Udluftningsventil
         </option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
<h3 class="specification-head">
  <a id="specification_5-accordion" class="custom-accordion" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <label for="specification_5">
   Not</label>
  </a>
</h3>
<div id="specification_5-accordion-content" class="two-fields accordian-specification">
  <div class="select-box">
    <select name="specification_5" id="specification_5" class="specification-option " onchange="selectSpec(this,'','','','');">
       <option class="a-layout" value="26">
            Not hele vejen rundt
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="23">
            Ingen not
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="24">
            Not i bunden
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="25">
            Not sider og top
         </option>
        
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
<h3 class="specification-head">
  <a id="specification_6-accordion" class="custom-accordion" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <label for="specification_6">
   Garanti</label>
  </a>
</h3>
<div id="specification_6-accordion-content" class="two-fields accordian-specification">
  <div class="select-box">
    <select name="specification_6" id="specification_6" class="specification-option " onchange="selectSpec(this,'','','','');">
         <option class="a-layout" selected="selected" value="27">
            10 års garanti
         </option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

My code also available on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dadwxu4r/12/)

Comment: You can not hide `<option>` tags cross browser. It is not supported in some like IE Choices are remove/replace or disable/enable

Comment: No worry about it i am generating div based on this so i will manage it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer

HTML Code
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dadwxu4r/15/)

```
 <h3 class="specification-head">
   <a id="specification_23-accordion" class="custom-accordion" href="javascript:void(0)">
   <label for="specification_23">
   Sprosser</label>
   </a>
</h3>
<div id="specification_23-accordion-content" class="two-fields accordian-specification">
   <div class="select-box">
      <select name="specification_23" id="specification_23" class="crossbaroption specification-option "  onchange="selectSpec(this,'','','','');">
         <option class="a-layout" value="50">
            25mm energisprosser
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="51">
            40mm energisprosser
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="52">
            55mm energisprosser
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="53">
            85 mm gennemgående sprosser
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="54">
            18mm indvendige energisprosser
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="55">
            26mm indvendige energisprosser
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="56">
            45mm indvendige energisprosser
         </option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<h3 class="specification-head" style="display: block;">
   <a id="specification_25-accordion" class="custom-accordion" href="javascript:void(0)">
   <label for="specification_25">
   Udluftningsventil</label>
   </a>
</h3>
<div id="specification_25-accordion-content" class="two-fields accordian-specification">
   <div class="select-box">
      <select name="specification_25" id="specification_25" class="specification-option "  onchange="selectSpec(this,'','','','');">
         <option class="a-layout" selected="selected" value="75">
            Ingen udluftningsventil
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="198">
            Udluftningsventil
         </option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<h3 class="specification-head">
   <a id="specification_5-accordion" class="custom-accordion" href="javascript:void(0)">
   <label for="specification_5">
   Not</label>
   </a>
</h3>
<div id="specification_5-accordion-content" class="two-fields accordian-specification">
   <div class="select-box">
      <select name="specification_5" id="specification_5" class="specification-option "  onchange="selectSpec(this,'','','','');">
       <option class="a-layout" value="26">
            Not hele vejen rundt
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="23">
            Ingen not
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="24">
            Not i bunden
         </option>
         <option class="a-layout" value="25">
            Not sider og top
         </option>

      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<h3 class="specification-head">
   <a id="specification_6-accordion" class="custom-accordion" href="javascript:void(0)">
   <label for="specification_6">
   Garanti</label>
   </a>
</h3>
<div id="specification_6-accordion-content" class="two-fields accordian-specification">
   <div class="select-box">
      <select name="specification_6" id="specification_6" class="specification-option "  onchange="selectSpec(this,'','','','');">
         <option class="a-layout" selected="selected" value="27">
            10 års garanti
         </option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the js code is as below.Need to slightly modify json array.

```
 var dependentspecArray= '{"width":{"50":{"parentoptions":["Bundtrin"],"childoptions":["Dørhåndtag"],"parentvalue":["Hårdttræ bundtrin"],"childvalue":["Håndtag for skydedør"]}},"height":{"50":{"parentoptions":["Sprosser","Sprosser","Sprosser"],"childoptions":["Udluftningsventil_40mm energisprosser","Not_55mm energisprosser","Not_55mm energisprosser"],"parentvalue":["40mm energisprosser_all","55mm energisprosser_Not sider og top","55mm energisprosser_Ingen not"],"childvalue":["all_40mm energisprosser","Not sider og top_55mm energisprosser","Ingen not_55mm energisprosser"]}}}';

function selectSpec(ele) {

   var inputvalue = ele.value;
    var selectname = ele.name;
    var mainName = selectname.replace("specification_", "");
    param = "spectfication_" + mainName + "=" + inputvalue; //+"&color_type=1";
    var selectedvalue = jQuery.trim(jQuery('option:selected',ele).text());
    var selectedoption = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#' + selectname + '-accordion label').contents().get(0).nodeValue);
    restrictSpecification(selectedoption,selectedvalue);
}


function restrictSpecification(selectedoption,selectedvalue) {


    if (typeof dependentspecArray !== 'undefined') {
        var height = 50;
        jQuery.each(JSON.parse(dependentspecArray), function(firstkey, firstval) {

            if (firstkey == 'height') {

                jQuery.each(firstval, function(secondkey, secondval) {


                    if (height <= secondkey) {
                    var $i = 0;
                                if (selectedoption == secondval.parentoptions[$i]) {
                                 jQuery('.a-layout').each(function() {
                                //console.log(jQuery(this).parent('select').attr('id'));
                                      var selectIdInner = jQuery(this).parent('select').attr('id');

                        var loopoption = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#' + selectIdInner + '-accordion label').contents().get(0).nodeValue);

                                    var loopoptionvalue = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text());
                                    if(jQuery.inArray(selectedoption, secondval.parentoptions) != -1 && jQuery.inArray(selectedvalue+'_'+loopoptionvalue, secondval.parentvalue) != -1 && jQuery.inArray(loopoptionvalue+'_'+selectedvalue,secondval.childvalue != -1)) {
                                        jQuery(this).hide();


                                    }
                                     else {
                                        jQuery(this).show();


                                    }

                                   if(jQuery.inArray(selectedoption, secondval.parentoptions) != -1 && jQuery.inArray(selectedvalue+'_all', secondval.parentvalue) != -1 && jQuery.inArray('all_'+selectedvalue,secondval.childvalue) != -1 && jQuery.inArray(loopoption+'_'+selectedvalue, secondval.childoptions) !=-1)
{
                                            jQuery('#' + selectIdInner + '-accordion-content').prev('h3').hide();
                                            jQuery(this).parent('select').hide();


                                        }else{
                                            jQuery('#' + selectIdInner + '-accordion-content').prev('h3').show();
                                            jQuery(this).parent('select').show();
                                        }
                                });
                            }


                    }
                    $i++;
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```